# Simulate click of an element that is a sibling of the parent of the parent of a clicked element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, parent

I want to simulate the click on an element that is a sibling of the parent of the parent of a clicked element .i.e. the a in the li next to the li with the a.active in it. This doesn't work:

JQUERY

```
$('li.product').click(function() {
    $('a.active').parent().parent().next().find(a).click();

        });
```

HTML

```
<ul>
 <li class="product"><li>
 <li class="product"></li>
 <li class="product"></li>
</ul>


<ul>
    <li id="">
    <div class="page">
    <a class="active" href="javascript:function Z(){Z=""}Z()">1</a>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li id="">
    <div class="page">
    <a class="" href="javascript:function Z(){Z=""}Z()">2</a>
    </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you now the javascript:void(); command?

Comment: Your example has no `<li>` with the product class.

Comment: ok ill add it its from another list further up in the code

Answer (score 2):

You are missing quotes `''` in `.find()`:

that should be like this: http://jsfiddle.net/SbDKD/

```
$('a.active').parent().parent().next().find('a').click();
```

Answer (score 1):

the following works for me

```
$('li.product a.active').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().next().find('a').click();
    return false;
});
```

assuming we have an HTML like:

```
<li class="product">
  <div class="page">
     <a class="active" href="javascript:alert('click 1')">1</a>
   </div>
</li>
<li class="product" onclick="alert('tickle')">
    <div class="page">
        <a onclick="alert('tickle me')" href="javascript:alert('click 2');">2</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

(inline onclick handler in HTML only for easy testing of course).

Answer (score 0):

I would put the click listener on the a tag and use the .parents() function to find the parent li in order to find it regardless of how deep you are. Then find the a in the next element.

```
$('a').click(function() {
  $(this).parents('li').next().find('a').trigger('click');

});
```

The only problem is that they will all trigger their following elements. But if you only have two it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```css
li:has(> a) {
  /* styles to apply to the li tag */
}
```